# Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to XmlParser::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given, called in

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have a problem with my code and can't find the error. This code works with PHP 7.0 but not with PHP 5.6. I need it to work in PHP 5.6. The error :Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to XmlParser::__construct() must be an instance of string, string given.

```
class XmlParser
{
    private $xml;

    public function __construct($document)
    {
        $this->xml = simplexml_load_file($document);
    }

    public function xmlParserPICtn()
    {
        global $obj;
        
        $valuesPICtn = $this->xml->xpath("//OBJEKT[@ID='$obj']//BILD");
        foreach ($valuesPICtn as $PICelements) {
            $searchpattern = '@https://([^"]+)@';
            preg_match($searchpattern, $PICelements->PIC, $valuesPICt); //Search-String
            $display .= '<li data-thumb=https://';
            $display .= $valuesPICt[1];
            $display .= '>';
            $display .= '<img src=https://';
            $display .= $valuesPICt[1];
            $display .= '></li>';
        }
        
        return $display;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your web server on debug mode and see what you have in the server error.log. But, it's really not a good idea to use any more PHP 5.x. It's preferable to upgrade the php version to 7.x or, better, to 8.1

Comment: Yes you a right with the Upgrade,  but in my situation I can't upgrade the php. Other scripts won't work with php7.0